# Access list of available tables on Exact Online for instance sales orders

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

I would like to access the list of available tables on Exact Online in the Query Tool. I've found some samples on superuser.com and stackoverflow.com with specific queries such as on `transactionlines`, but seem unable to get a complete list and the API descriptions are not complete.

Is there any way to retrieve an overview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently three ways to find the list of available tables:

## Option 1

- Go to the query tool.
- Choose the tab "Available Objects".
- Open the alias of the data container (when solely connected to one country it will probably be "ExactOnline").
- Choose one of the available catalog: `CodeValues` for domains such as GL account types and their values, `ExactOnlineREST` for all REST API end points and `ExactOnlineXML` for all XML API end points.
- If necessary open a schema.
- There you will find a list.
- Right-click to get field list or press F4 on the name of the table in the editor.

## Option 2

In the data dictionary, you will find a table named `systemtables`. That one contains all available tables and views. In SQL query:

```
select *
from   systemtables@datadictionary
```

## Option 3

The auto-completion in the editor will try to offer you suggestions when you type. However, the list of options is so large that you will need to more than just a few characters, so it is not always helpful. But if you know the first 5-10 characters, it will guide you.